# ./index.js is recognized as a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

./commands/hello.js:

```js
const discord = require("discord.js")
const client = require("./index.js").client
const { prefix } = require("./config/config.json")
const { hello } = "./config/config.js"

//modules
module.exports = () => {

//onClient
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}hello`)) return

    //creating the embed 
    const embed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle("test")
          .setAuthor("Sanke")
          .addField("Test", "this is a test")
          .setDescription("This is a test commmand")


    //message send
    message.channel.send({
        content:"",
        embeds: [embed],
        files: []
    })
})
}
```

index.js:

```js
const { Client,Intents } =  require("discord.js")
const { token } = require("./config/config.json")
const fs = require('fs')

//Client init
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]})
exports.client = client


client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log("First time seeing ya face on discord :)")
    client.user.setActivity("First time here :D")
})

//comand Handler
const command = require("./commands/hello")
command()

client.login(token)
```

**Problem:**
-in ./commands/hello.js is recognized as a module,not a target file. I don't know what to do...I tried to make the command handler with the const command = require("./commands(commands directory)/hello(the command file)")
-**Error:**
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

```js
Error: Cannot find module './index.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/sanki/Desktop/Sanke_<:>/proiecte/theBot/commands/hello.js
- /Users/sanki/Desktop/Sanke_<:>/proiecte/theBot/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sanki/Desktop/Sanke_<:>/proiecte/theBot/commands/hello.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/sanki/Desktop/Sanke_<:>/proiecte/theBot/commands/hello.js',
    '/Users/sanki/Desktop/Sanke_<:>/proiecte/theBot/index.js'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the code you shared that you're trying to require `./index.js` inside `commands/hello.js`. Shouldn't that be `../index.js`?

The next problem you're likely to encounter is a circular dependency - each file requires the other.

Can you remove the require of `index.js` in `hello.js` and pass the `client` to the hello command directly? E.g.

**index.js**

```js
const { Client, Intents } =  require("discord.js")
const { token } = require("./config/config.json")
const fs = require('fs')

//Client init
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]})
exports.client = client


client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log("First time seeing ya face on discord :)")
    client.user.setActivity("First time here :D")
})

//comand Handler
const command = require("./commands/hello")

// CHANGE >> PASS CLIENT TO COMMAND
command(client)

client.login(token)
```